# Importing a Shapefile in SpaceStat with GeoTools

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I've just discovered the GeoTools tutorial to generate a Shapefile from a CSV containing a list of cities.
I've managed to make it work but when I try to create a new Geography in SpaceStat, importing the newly created Shapefile, I get an error that says:

```
Import failed: No valid objects were found
```

I tried to take a look at SpaceStat docs but I didn't find anything about this error. Are there particular requirements for the Shapefile to be imported in SpaceStat?

Here's the code I use to generate the shapefile.

```
public class Csv2Shape {

SimpleFeatureType TYPE = null;

public Csv2Shape() {

    System.out.println("Constructor");
    try {
        TYPE = DataUtilities.createType("Location", "location:Point:srid=4326," + "name:String," + "number:Integer");
        System.out.println("Type init: "+ TYPE);
    } catch (SchemaException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("csv", null);
    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }
    Csv2Shape csvshape = new Csv2Shape();
    System.out.println("TYPE:"+csvshape.TYPE);


    /*
     * We create a FeatureCollection into which we will put each Feature created from a record
     * in the input csv data file
     */
    List<SimpleFeature> collection = new ArrayList<SimpleFeature>();
    /*
     * GeometryFactory will be used to create the geometry attribute of each feature (a Point
     * object for the location)
     */
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();

    SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(csvshape.TYPE);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    try {
        /* First line of the data file is the header */
        String line = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Header: " + line);

        for (line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
            if (line.trim().length() > 0) { // skip blank lines
                String tokens[] = line.split("\\,");

                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
                String name = tokens[2].trim();
                int number = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].trim());

                /* Longitude (= x coord) first ! */
                Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));

                featureBuilder.add(point);
                featureBuilder.add(name);
                featureBuilder.add(number);
                SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
                collection.add(feature);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }

    File newFile = getNewShapeFile(file);

    ShapefileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();

    Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
    params.put("url", newFile.toURI().toURL());
    params.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);

    ShapefileDataStore newDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore) dataStoreFactory.createNewDataStore(params);
    newDataStore.createSchema(csvshape.TYPE);

    /*
     * You can comment out this line if you are using the createFeatureType method (at end of
     * class file) rather than DataUtilities.createType
     */
    newDataStore.forceSchemaCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);


    /*
     * Write the features to the shapefile
     */
    Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");

    String typeName = newDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = newDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

    if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
        SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;

        featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);

        try {
            SimpleFeatureCollection sfcollection = DataUtilities.collection(collection);
            featureStore.addFeatures(sfcollection);
            transaction.commit();

        } catch (Exception problem) {
            problem.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();

        } finally {
            transaction.close();
        }
        System.exit(0); // success!
    } else {
        System.out.println(typeName + " does not support read/write access");
        System.exit(1);
    }


}




/**
 * Prompt the user for the name and path to use for the output shapefile
 * 
 * @param csvFile
 *            the input csv file used to create a default shapefile name
 * 
 * @return name and path for the shapefile as a new File object
 */
private static File getNewShapeFile(File csvFile) {
    String path = csvFile.getAbsolutePath();
    String newPath = path.substring(0, path.length() - 4) + ".shp";

    JFileDataStoreChooser chooser = new JFileDataStoreChooser("shp");
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Save shapefile");
    chooser.setSelectedFile(new File(newPath));

    int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

    if (returnVal != JFileDataStoreChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        // the user cancelled the dialog
        System.exit(0);
    }

    File newFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    if (newFile.equals(csvFile)) {
        System.out.println("Error: cannot replace " + csvFile);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return newFile;
}

}
```

Comment: can you open the shapefile in any other tools (QGis)?

Comment: I tried to open it with QGIS but it seems to be empty even if the associated dbf seems to contain the correct data. Any idea?

Comment: in that case we need to see the GeoTools code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have been caught out by a (recent) update to the shapefile read/writer code. The geometry field of a shapefile must be called the_geom (if you check http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html you'll see it is there). This is an attempt to fit in with how other programs interpret the ShapeFile specification (I believe).